# useMemo does not rerender dynamic controls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have list of controls which are sent by backend. Sometimes it is necessary to update options of dropdown control.

I thought that it would work. However, `memoizedControls` is not rerendered.

I believe that it should work like this:

- press the button and `handleFieldsChange()` function is triggered.
- then `setTechSpec('')` sets `techSpec` to ''
- then custom hook `usePerson` is triggered because it has `techSpec` in its dependency array
- then `memoizedControls` is triggered because it has `personList` in its dependency array
- and `updateControlOptions()` updates options of `controls`

However, UI does not have rerendered and new options of `personList` is not rerendered.

```
const [techSpec, setTechSpec] = useState('1')
const [personList, isLoadingPersonList] = usePerson(techSpec)

const handleFieldsChange = (changedValue: EditablePersonValues) => {
    setTechSpec('')
    fetchPerson()}

const updateControlOptions = (
    controls: FormControl[],
    controlName: string,
    newOptions: SelectOption[],
) =>
    controls.map((control) =>
        control.name === controlName
            ? { ...control, options: newOptions }
            : { ...control },)

const memoizedControls = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('memoizedControls')
    if (personList.length > 0)
        return updateControlOptions(
            controls,
            'personId',
            personList,
        )
    return controls
}, [controls, personList])

const fetchPerson = () => {
    const localTechSpecification = form.getFieldValue('techSpecification')
    setTechSpec(localTechSpecification)
    form.setFieldsValue({ personId: undefined })
}
```

and:

```
return (
{memoizedControls.map(
        ({ name, type, displayName, required, options, measure }) => {                          
            return (
                <MyDynamicField
                    key={name}
                    name={name}
                    controlType={type}
                    displayName={`${displayName}${measure ? `, ${measure}` : ''}`}
                    required={required}
                    value={value}
                    itemOptions={options}
                />
            )
        },
    )}
)
```

My question is that "usePerson" hook is being re-executed when the "techSpec" state value changes. `personList` is updated. But `memoizedControls` does not show new values of `personList`. Maybe do you know the reason of why `memoizedControls` is not rerendered?

Please, does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you created a codesandbox (or preferably an embedded [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)) that reproduces this issue so we can help debug.

Comment: @NickParsons maybe is it possible to make some suggestions without sandbox because there are so many dependencies should be imported in sandbox. Thank for your wish to help

Comment: You don't need to recreate your entire project within the codesanbox, just the code that would be required to reproduce your issue. It's a bit hard to see what's running/not running without having something that we can run and play with. From this code alone I can't spot anything, maybe someone else can though.

Comment: @NickParsons thank you very much. The error was not in the above code, the error was in component `MyDynamicField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code was fine, the problem was in component `<MyDynamicField/>`.

So `itemOptions` should be added in dependency array `[height, width, itemOptions])` of `useEffect`. So code would look like this:

```
export const MyDynamicField = ({
    name,
    controlType,
    displayName,
    required,
    value,
    itemOptions,
    moulds,
    initData,
    height,
    width,
}: Props) => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState<SelectOption[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const prepareOptions = filterOptions(
            name,
            moulds,
            initData,
            itemOptions,
            height,
            width,
        )
        setOptions(prepareOptions)
    }, [height, width, itemOptions])
    return (
        <ControlFactory
            key={name}
            name={name}
            controlType={controlType}
            displayName={displayName}
            required={required}
            options={options}
            value={value}
        />
    )
}
```

and then `useEffect` and `useState` can be removed and `useMemo` can be used:

```
export const MyDynamicField = ({
    name,
    controlType,
    displayName,
    required,
    value,
    itemOptions,
    moulds,
    initData,
    height,
    width,
}: Props) => {
    const options = useMemo(
        () => filterOptions(name, moulds, initData, itemOptions, height, width),
        [name, moulds, initData, itemOptions, height, width],
    )

    return (
        <ControlFactory
            key={name}
            name={name}
            controlType={controlType}
            displayName={displayName}
            required={required}
            options={options}
            value={value}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
const MyComponent = ({ personList }) => {
  const [techSpec, setTechSpec] = useState('1');
  const [isLoadingPersonList, setIsLoadingPersonList] = useState(false);

  const handleFieldsChange = (changedValue) => {
    setTechSpec('');
    fetchPerson();
  };

  const updateControlOptions = (controls, controlName, newOptions) =>
    controls.map((control) =>
      control.name === controlName
        ? { ...control, options: newOptions }
        : { ...control }
    );

  const memoizedControls = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('memoizedControls');
    if (personList.length > 0) {
      return updateControlOptions(controls, 'personId', personList);
    }
    return controls;
  }, [controls, personList]); // personList is included in the dependency array

  const fetchPerson = () => {
    const localTechSpecification = form.getFieldValue('techSpecification');
    setTechSpec(localTechSpecification);
    form.setFieldsValue({ personId: undefined });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {memoizedControls.map(({ name, type, displayName, required, options, measure }) => (
        <DynamicField
          key={name}
          name={name}
          controlType={type}
          displayName={`${displayName}${measure ? `, ${measure}` : ''}`}
          required={required}
          value={value}
          itemOptions={options}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: yeah, and this is desirable behavior.  `personList` is updated, but `memoizedControls` does not show new values of `personList`. Maybe do you know the reason of why `memoizedControls` is not rerendered?

Comment: the component that is responsible for rendering the memoizedControls value is using a PureComponent or a React.memo higher-order component, which prevents the component from re-rendering when its props do not change. In this case, you can either remove the PureComponent or React.memo higher-order component, or you can make sure that the component re-renders by changing one of its props when the personList value changes .

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of knowledge, but you show please it via code?

Comment: The only difference I've found is `const [isLoadingPersonList, setIsLoadingPersonList] = useState(false);` and the result is the same, controls are not rerendrered